# How do I filter my searches?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[So these are my movie cards.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/In2Zf.png)

[These are the properties of each of the movie card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iECc3.png)

So this is the onKeyPress :

```
onKeyPress={ onFavoritesSearch(event.target.value)}
```

I need to pass that value into my function, this is what i have so far :

```
    onFavoritesSearch = (event) => {
    if (event.key === "Enter") {
        this.state.sortedFavorites.filter(movie => movie.title.indexOf(event.target.value) === 0)
      }
}
```

How would I pass the value of the input inside the function?

Answer (score 1):

You should try this in your class:

```
filterFavoriteMovies = (search) => {
  this.state.favorites.filter(movie => movie.title.indexOf(search) === 0)
}
```

And then call it like `this.filterFavoriteMovies(evt.target.value)`

Although I'll recommend you to handle it all in the function, it's not recommended to declare the function in your JSX ([reason from the official docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#arrow-function-in-render))

It would look like this:

```
filterFavoriteMovies = (event) => {
  if (event.key === "Enter") {
    this.state.favorites.filter(movie => movie.title.indexOf(event.target.value) === 0)
  }
}
```

And in your JSX like: `onKeyPress={this.filterFavoriteMovies}`

Comment: There's one error, I used the top code : TypeError: Cannot read property 'filter' of undefined

Comment: Surely, change `this.state.favorites` to where your movies array is located, in case of the state, but you didn't showed that, adapt it

Comment: I updated the example, the functions got exchanged somehow on save

Comment: But that is where my movies array is located. https://i.stack.imgur.com/iECc3.png

Comment: Did you use the updated one? If that doesn't work just bind `this` to the function in the `constructor` method

Comment: Either favorites is null, or the function isn't getting `this`, so it can't get the state of your component

Comment: If you want, update your code with your whole component so I can be more helpful to you

Comment: Hey are u still there?

Comment: I'm here, tell me

Comment: Change `onKeyPress={ onFavoritesSearch(event.target.value)} ` to `onKeyPress={this.onFavoritesSearch}  `

Comment: It doesn't need this and it won't work anways cuz  const {
            favorites,
            onFavoritesSearch,
            sortByTitle,
            sortByDate,
            sortByPopularity,
        } = this.props;                                                                                                               so it doesn't need this

Comment: Remove `this` then, just do `onKeyPress={onFavoritesSearch}`